# Dequeue final node in circular linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, circular-queue

When I am trying to dequeue the final node in a circular linked list based queue in C++ I am getting a segmentation fault. The rest of the elements before the final one are removed successfully, its just the last one and it seems to be an issue with deallocation however the only log from terminal is Segmentation fault: 11. Could someone help me understand why I am getting this behavior. I've pasted the complete implementation file below incase it is a problem with the Enqueue function or constructors.

```
#include "BQUEUE.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

BQUEUE::BQUEUE(): front(nullptr) {}

BQUEUE::BQUEUE(const BQUEUE & queue){
  bqnode *temp = queue.front;
  while (temp->next != queue.front){
    Enqueue(temp->time);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  Enqueue(temp->time);
}

BQUEUE::~BQUEUE(){
  bqnode *current = front;
  while (current->next != front)
    Dequeue();
}

void BQUEUE::Dequeue(){
  // Empty queue
  if (front == nullptr){
    return;
  } else if (front->next == front){
    front->next = nullptr;
    delete front;
    front = nullptr;
  } else {
    bqnode *temp = front, *current = front;
    while (current->next != front)
      current = current->next;
    front = front->next;
    current->next = front;
    delete temp;
  }
}

void BQUEUE::Print(){
  bqnode *temp = front;
  while (temp->next != front){
    cout << temp->time << endl;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << temp->time << endl;
}

void BQUEUE::Enqueue(int i){
  bqnode *newNode = new bqnode;
  newNode->time = i;
  if (front == nullptr){
    front = newNode;
    front->next = front;
  } else {
    newNode->next = front;
    bqnode *previous = front;
    if (previous->next == front){
      front->next = newNode;
      return;
    }
    while (previous->next != front)
      previous = previous->next;
    previous->next = newNode;
  }
}
```

DRIVER:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BQUEUE.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  BQUEUE k;
  k.Enqueue(60);
  k.Dequeue(); // Segmentation fault occurs here
}
```

HEADER:

```
#ifndef BQUEUE_H
#define BQUEUE_H

class bqnode {
public:
  int time;
  bqnode *prev, *next;
};

class BQUEUE {
  public:
    BQUEUE();
    ~BQUEUE();
    BQUEUE(const BQUEUE &);
    void Enqueue(int);
    void Dequeue( );
    void Print( );
  private:
    bqnode *front;
  };

#endif
```

Comment: A debugger would help here, but just work thru on paper what happens in the BQUEUE destructor when you all `delete front;`.

Comment: *Could someone help me understand why I am getting this behavior* -- Where is your test data?  Also, why not test the simplest case (if you're not already doing so) -- just add two nodes and delete them.  Or add a single node and attempt to delete it. -- *I've pasted the complete implementation file* -- what is required is a [mcve], and an implementation file is not that.  We need code that all we have to do is copy and paste into a compiler, run the code, and duplicate the results.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My apologies, was just trying to share the smallest code sample possible to make it easy for people to read through. It immediately doesn't work if trying to add one node and then remove it. I'll update the question.

Comment: I gave an answer, but in general, if you used the debugger and single-stepped through your code, you should have found the issue easily.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but keep an eye out for the [Rule of Three and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is this:

```
void BQUEUE::Dequeue() {
    // Empty queue
    if (front == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    else if (front->next == front) {  // <-- This is invoked when there is only one node remaining
        front->next = nullptr;
        delete front;
        front = nullptr;  // <--- This is now nullptr
    }
...
```

Then in the destructor, you didn't check if the `front` is `nullptr`:

```
BQUEUE::~BQUEUE() {
    bqnode *current = front;  // <-- No check to see if front is nullptr
    while (current->next != front)
        Dequeue();
}
```

You then access `current->next`, which is invalid since `current` is `nullptr`.  The fix is to simply check if `front` is `nullptr`, and if it is, there is nothing to do.

```
BQUEUE::~BQUEUE() {
    if ( front )
    {
        bqnode *current = front;  
        while (current->next != front)
            Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped tons, I found my issues. This was the first one which brought my attention in the debugger to issues when front was nullptr. I forgot to initialize front = nullptr initially in the copy constructor and in my print function I was not handling the case for front == nullptr. Sorry for the beginner questions, I'm pretty new to C++. Thanks again!